# Cant setup eclipse workspace for 1.12.2 forge

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

Each time i try to setup a workspace for 1.12.2 forge i get an error saying.

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
Could not run build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-bin.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  
BobboClient line 0 Gradle Error Marker
```

Comment: What gradle commands and other steps do you mean by 'I try to setup a workspace'?
I just downloaded and extracted the 1.12.2 mdk, ran `gradlew genEclipseRuns` twice (randomly failed the first time) followed by `gradlew eclipse` and it built without problems.

Comment: hey sorry for taking so long to answer i ended up just using intellij and by setting up a workspace i mean exactly what you just said running both of those commands and opening it as a gradle project